# Why is the nonpregnant female mouse (housed with a pregnant female) attacking me?

Tags: aggression, mice

I have 3 female mice one of them is mine and she is pregnant and about to give birth any day now. The other two mice are my friends, she’s going away for a month and I’m looking after them. They get along perfectly fine with my female mouse.

My friend's two mice have been with me for two weeks now they are a little skittish but will eat from my hands. Today I went to check on my pregnant mouse like I do everyday and when I put my hand into the cage one of my friends mice started to bite my hand. Like it was attacking me and it wouldn’t stop. I’m not sure why it’s doing this, maybe because the babies are coming soon and it can sense it? I’m not sure